# Avoid Jenkins add as users Committers

Tags: jenkins

Currently, Jenkins add as a user any known user of Jenkins plus any user mentioned in a commit message.

[image]

This effectively means that if you are managing several projects in Jenkins instance and each project with tenths of developers then it is really hard to maintain.

Another side effect is that JENKINS_HOME/users are populated with one xml for each of these users, so Jenkins becomes somehow unmanageable. Not the end of the world, that's true, but at the same time you start seeing users from outside of team/organization.

So, is there any way to disable this behaviour?

Thak you so much.